Designing Terraform resource than can be created from multiple sources
Lets Say I have Pizza App and Pizza can be created/managed from multiple sources
From  JSON
{
 "name": "Margherita"
 "price" :10
 "toppings:": []
 "allergies": []
 // imagine dozens more fields for some reason
}

From  .txt file
name=Margherita;price=10

And somehow I  want to create one unified Terraform resource that can accommodated those multiple inputs
My first Idea was to create resource like this, which will be similar to my Pizza Json model
resource "pizza" "p1" {
  name="Margherita"
  price= 10
  toppings={}
  allergies= {}
}

And create data source to transform pizza.txt to pizza Terraform model
Data source will use API to transform pizza.txt to Pizza Model which be translated to Pizza Terraform Model  (Output of data source == input of pizza resource)
data "pizza_txt" t1 {
   file = "pizza.txt"
}

and use output of datasource as input to my resource
resource "pizza" "p1" {
  name=data.pizza_txt.t1.name
  price= name=data.pizza_txt.t1.pice
  toppings={
    name = name=data.pizza_txt.t1.tooping[n].name
  }
}

but lest say my Pizza have hundreds of attributes so passing one by one is very cumbersome for Users that want to use pizza.txt  as Input
and I'm looking a way to better solve this problem
Something like
resource "pizza" "p1" {
  pizza=data.pizza_txt.t1
}

But this as far as I know is not possible in terraform, pass "complex"  attributes from data source to resource
Is there better way to design Terraform resource than can be managed from multiple "sources" and don't have to pass each attribute from data source to resource one by one
Don't know how to design terraform resource for API that can accept input from multiple sources

This is a requirement (I believe) because of the HCL2/struct encode/decode, and therefore cannot be circumvented.
